# How to add ggrepel text for ggplot geom_line density

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

I have the following code:

```
set.seed(10)
foo <- data.frame(
  v2=sample(c(1,2,3),size=10,rep=T),
  v3=as.factor(sample(c('cat','dog'),10,rep=T))
)

library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
ggplot(foo, aes(x=v2, colour=v3, group=v3)) +
  geom_line(aes(group=v3), stat='density', alpha=0.3)
```

Which produces this plot:

[image]

I try adding this:

```
 geom_text_repel(aes(x=v2, label = v3)) +
```

But it gives:

```
Error: geom_text_repel requires the following missing aesthetics: y
```

My question is how can I use ggrepel to show labels as indicate in the picture above?

Answer (score 5):

You could do

```
set.seed(10)
foo <- data.frame(
  v2=sample(c(1,2,3),size=10,rep=T),
  v3=as.factor(sample(c('cat','dog'),10,rep=T))
)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(foo, aes(x=v2, colour=v3, group=v3)) +
  geom_line(aes(group=v3), stat='density', alpha=0.3) -> p
pdat <- ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]
idx <- sample(seq_len(nrow(pdat)), 20)
p + ggrepel::geom_text_repel(
  aes(x,y,label=txt), 
  cbind(pdat[idx,], txt=paste0("txt", seq_along(idx))), 
  inherit.aes=F, 
  show.legend = F, 
  color="red", 
  segment.colour = "black", 
  min.segment.length = unit(0, "lines")
)
```